Laravel 9 -the audio failed to upload just in production server it works correctly in my local environment
I have a contract Controller where I can upload the audio files against each contract and it works fine on local environment but when I try to upload on the server, it doesn't work. When I try to upload a mp3 file, it doesn't upload the file, it just refresh the page without uploading it. Please help me
ContractController
  public function upload(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'enregistrements.*' => 'required|mimes:mp3|max:10240',
        ]);
    
        $contract = Contract::findOrFail($id);
    
       
        foreach ($request->file('enregistrements') as $file) {
            // Get original file name and sanitize it
            $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $sanitizedFileName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.]/', '_', $originalName);
            
            // Store the file with sanitized name in 'public/enregistrements' directory
            $filePath = $file->storeAs('enregistrements', $sanitizedFileName, 'public');
            
            // Save the file path in the database
            AudioRecording::create([
                'contract_id' => $contract->id,
                'file_path' => $filePath,
            ]);
        }
        
    
        return redirect()->route('contracts.index')->with('success', 'Enregistrements uploadés avec succès.');
    }


Upload Modal
<!-- Upload Modal -->
@foreach ($contracts as $contract)
<div class="modal fade profileModal-modal" id="profileModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="profileModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header" id="profileModalLabel">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Ajouter <b>Enregistrements</b></h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x">
                    <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line>
                    <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="uploadForm" action="{{ route('contracts.upload', $contract->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input class="form-control file-upload-input" type="file" id="formFile" name="enregistrements[]" accept=".mp3" multiple required>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-danger mt-2 mb-2 btn-no-effect" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-2 btn-no-effect">Upload</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach


What does "it wont work" mean? Blank page? Wrong audio file uploaded? Did you check folder permissions?

like when i try to upload the mp3 file the page just refresh and dont show me the success message also i can not see my file uploaded or been saved in the database that's happen only when i upload my project to the server in my localhost it work very good

Have you tried fixing your HTML? Your <form> is closing way too late. Did you check folder permissions?

can you please explain more how i can check the folder permissions?

do you mean i need to consult my .htaccess file ?

Did you check the max upload size & max post size for PHP & your webserver? Apache2/nginx?

yes i have check that and here is what i have in my server called Plesk Obsidian post_max_size is 16M and upload_max_filesize is 16M and file_uploads is ON

Try to also check your log files.

Add a try catch and log the exception, you will find the issue, most probably it's because of the application_url value mismatch in ENV
try something like this
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log; 
 try {
        $request->validate([
            'enregistrements.*' => 'required|mimes:mp3|max:10240',
        ]);

        $contract = Contract::findOrFail($id);


        foreach ($request->file('enregistrements') as $file) {
            // Get original file name and sanitize it
            $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $sanitizedFileName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.]/', '_', $originalName);

            // Store the file with sanitized name in 'public/enregistrements' directory
            $filePath = $file->storeAs('enregistrements', $sanitizedFileName, 'public');

            // Save the file path in the database
            AudioRecording::create([
                'contract_id' => $contract->id,
                'file_path' => $filePath,
            ]);
        }
    }catch (\Throwable $th) {
        Log::info($th->getMessage());
    }

and check your env
APP_URL=https://example.com //provide your domain here


It seems like there is file permission issue. You can check the file permission by using ls -l enregistrements. check whether you have write permission or not. you can give permission using sudo chmod 755 path/of/folder.
other than this you can add try catch block to get the errors.
public function upload(Request $request, $id)
{
    try {
        $request->validate([
            'enregistrements.*' => 'required|mimes:mp3|max:10240',
        ]);

        $contract = Contract::findOrFail($id);


        foreach ($request->file('enregistrements') as $file) {
            // Get original file name and sanitize it
            $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $sanitizedFileName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.]/', '_', $originalName);

            // Store the file with sanitized name in 'public/enregistrements' directory
            $filePath = $file->storeAs('enregistrements', $sanitizedFileName, 'public');

            // Save the file path in the database
            AudioRecording::create([
                'contract_id' => $contract->id,
                'file_path' => $filePath,
            ]);
        }


        return redirect()->route('contracts.index')->with('success', 'Enregistrements uploadés avec succès.');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->route('contracts.index')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }
}

